# Excel replace each char in a string contained in another list

Tags: excel, indexing, replace, excel-formula, encoding

I have 2 tables, table A and table B, on column G I would like to encode only the Hebrew and spaces, but using the ENCODEURL encodes the whole string. I found a workaround and I wrote in Table A each of the chars I'm trying to replace and the encoded value.
I want to search the string in column F for any of the chars that are in column B and replace (or substitute) them in the values in column C.

any help will be much appreciated.
[image]

**Data in my image as text:**

```
description DECODED ENCODED
letter  א   %D7%90
letter  ב   %D7%91
letter  ג   %D7%92
letter  ד   %D7%93
letter  ה   %D7%94
letter  ו   %D7%95
letter  ז   %D7%96
letter  ח   %D7%97
letter  ט   %D7%98
letter  י   %D7%99
letter  כ   %D7%9B
letter  ל   %D7%9C
letter  מ   %D7%9E
letter  נ   %D7%A0
letter  ס   %D7%A1
letter  ע   %D7%A2
letter  פ   %D7%A4
letter  צ   %D7%A6
letter  ק   %D7%A7
letter  ר   %D7%A8
letter  ש   %D7%A9
letter  ת   %D7%AA
letter  ן   %D7%9F
letter  ם   %D7%9D
letter  ץ   %D7%A5
letter  ף   %D7%A3
letter  ך   %D7%9A
space       %20


Link
test/ם/
```

Desired result should be: `test/%D7%9D/` and not `test/%D7%9E/`
(**D** in the end not **E**)

Comment: Do you have this data as markdown sample data?

Comment: Do you mean an excel file? yes I do, is it necessary? should I include the substrings I have in the example in the body of my question so you can copy paste?

Comment: I meant actual markdown sample data we can copy. SCreenshots are not very helpfull unless you want us to retype all of the data. Copy paste the data into the question and create a table out of it.

Comment: You're right, check now please, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Microsoft365, try:

[image]

Formula in `F2`:

```
=LET(X,MID(E2,SEQUENCE(LEN(E2)),1),CONCAT(IFERROR(INDEX(C$2:C$24,MATCH(X,B$2:B$24,0)),X)))
```

I tried to swap the `IFERROR()`, `INDEX()` and `MATCH()` part with `XLOOKUP()` but it didn't work since the latter won't take an array as a lookup-value.

---

Right, after your updated question I think you could use:

```
=LET(X,MID(E2,SEQUENCE(LEN(E2)),1),CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(X,B$2:B$29,0)),ENCODEURL(X),X)))
```

Now you can drop the 1st and 3rd column alltogether too.

[image]

Comment: as always, you're the best hands down. I owe you a lot this week haha

Comment: I have a small change. I need to add 5 more letters. in Hebrew there are letters that are basically the same letter but when they are in the end of a word they are different. I the link "test/אדום/" for example should be different, and i'm getting the other version of the letter. is there a way to do INDEX MATCH but the MATCH part will be EXACT?

Comment: @Kobe2424, you should elaborate this. Either in your current question or maybe even in a new question? That's up to you. I'm not sure what you mean with an exact match since that is what the 3rd parameter inside `MATCH()` does allready. I don't know Hebrew, so I also don't know what letters you are talking about. It is worth mentioning this in your data. Hence why you may need a new question alltogether.

Comment: I've updated the values in my original question and the link also. Notice that the link have the letter in row 26 but the MATCH returning the letter in row 15, this is due to it's basically the same letter but the char is different (the ENCODED value in column C is also different), MATCH and EXACT are different formulas: MATCH will find for example "f" as "F" in the range, but EXACT won't. So I need I to add it somehow to the formula you sent before

Comment: Works :)
Eventually we didn't use the LOOKUP right? we've just used ENCODE again

Comment: @Kobe2424, yes. Only used `MATCH()` to test if we needed to encode the character or not.

Comment: Got it, great job as always.